# What is a moving time window and how is it used to throttle requests?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, throttling

In the [aiohttp_scraper](https://github.com/jgontrum/aiohttp-scraper) package it says

> Uses a moving time window to throttle requests per domain and proxy

but I don't understand it. What does it mean?

What would happen if I for example chose this values?

```
window_size_in_minutes=1,
max_requests_per_window=1,
```

Would this mean only one request per minute for a proxy in a domain, but other proxies are still allowed requesting that domain, and the same proxy is still allowed requesting other domains?

Comment: It means that it paces the rate of requests to maintain a fixed number of requests in the "window" from the current time looking backward by a fixed duration.

Comment: With the choice you gave, it would do something like make 1 initial request (the max requests per window) and then queue an event one minute in the future. When that event time is reached, the event is processed, decrementing the number in the window to zero, so it would send a new request to re-fill the window.  This is simple behavior, but in practice it defeats the whole reason for the window, which is to deal with variations in latency.